# Issues installing new ruby version using rbenv

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv

I am trying to install ruby 2.5.0 on my system (macOS High Sierra) using rbenv but i'm facing a weird issue as the brew instructions are out of date:

```
djeustinezzz:~ JUSTINE$ rbenv install rbx-2.5.0

ERROR: Rubinius will not be able to compile using Apple's LLVM-based 
build tools on OS X. You will need to install LLVM 3.5 first.

TO FIX THE PROBLEM: Install Homebrew's llvm package with this
command: brew tap homebrew/versions ; brew install llvm35

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.13.6 using ruby-build 20160130)
```

The version 3.5 of LLVM was deleted. After googling here is what i've done:

```
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-core
brew install llvm@3.7
```

But nothing changed.

Homebrew, rbenv and ruby-build are installed and up-to-date.

Precision on why i'm doing this: i just installed Rails 5 on my computer and when i run the server, i have this error:

```
rbenv: version `ruby-2.5.0' is not installed (set by /Users/JUSTINE/desktop/code/test_five/.ruby-version)
```

When i run `ruby -v`, the output is `ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin17]` .

Any idea?

Comment: Can you do `rbenv install 2.5.0`. Then `rbenv local 2.5.0` and `rbenv rehash` inside your project directory.

Comment: i have an error when running `rbenv install 2.5.0` : `ruby-build: definition not found: 2.5.0 ; The following versions contain `2.5.0' in the name: rbx-2.5.0 ; See all available versions with `rbenv install --list'. ; If the version you need is missing, try upgrading ruby-build:  brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build`. I have tried upgrading ruby-build already but nothing changed.

Comment: You don't have the formula's updated. that's why. Hold on.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need such an old version? The current release of Rubinius is 3.107, 2.5.0 is *really* old. (January 2015, I think.) Since the JIT compiler uses LLVM, you need a matching installation of LLVM with a compatible API.

Comment: When you run the following `rbenv install --list`, you should see `2.5.0`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna i don't see it... and when i run `rbenv install` with any `rbx-[version]` i get the same error message with the outdated brew instructions

Comment: You'll have to update your ruby build. you can go into `~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/` directory and do `git pull origin master`. After that see if `rbenv install --list` will have `2.5.0`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna i can't find any 'plugins' file under .rbenv (only have shims, version and versions). can't find `ruby-build` in `shims` either.

Comment: Something is not right here. How did you install rbenv ? `homebrew`

Comment: Let me put the steps, I follow when I'm installing `rbenv` and this works. Also, I'm not a fan of installing using `brew`, as if it works fine then everything is good, else lot of things seems messed. if you're ok doing so, then remove both `ruby-build` and `rbenv` using `brew uninstall`

Comment: I found the solution :) thanks for your help @KedarnagMukanahallipatna

Comment: No Problem. What was the fix ? Was it any of my solution or something you changed on your side ?

Answer (score 3):

Clone both rbenv and ruby-build using the below links

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

Now you'll have the ruby-build directory inside plugins.

```
cd ~/.rbenv
git pull
cd plugins/ruby-build
git pull
```

After this, you should `2.5.0` when you run `rbenv install --list`

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

So, what I'd do is try to see if you have the correct version of macOS command line tools installed. You could run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Or you could start from scratch with:

```
rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Then install the command line tools with the code above, or the better way which I found, was going directly to the Apple Developer site and downloading the command line tools package itself and installing that.

Install Command Line tools version 10.13 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

This issue also came up for me, but it came up when I started running Mojave. I believe it's the same thing here because I got the same errors.